# How can I know if C++ compiler make thread-safe static object code?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, gcc, visual-c++

In GCC, local static variable is thread-safe (by special function[`__cxa_guard_acquire`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/969fe59ca826b190a1529a6a655372c1d9676d99)) unless [`-fno-threadsafe-statics`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html) compiler option is given.

Similarly, MSVC 2015 and onward version support the same feature and can be disabled by  [`/Zc:threadSafeInit-`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-threadsafeinit-thread-safe-local-static-initialization).

Is there any macro or other features, like `__EXCEPTIONS` or `__GXX_RTTI` to check on compilation stage if such features are enabled or not? I think checking `__cplusplus` or `_MSC_VER` won't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there is one define `__cpp_threadsafe_static_init`.

> ### [SD-6: SG10 Feature Test Recommendations](https://isocpp.org/std/standing-documents/sd-6-sg10-feature-test-recommendations):
>
> #### C++11 features
>
> Significant features of C++11
>
> Doc. No.  Title   Primary Section     Macro name  Value   Header
>
> **N2660**     Dynamic Initialization and Destruction with Concurrency     3.6     `__cpp_threadsafe_static_init`  200806  *predefined*

**CLang** - http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#ts ([github.com](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/96c9689f478d292390b76efcea35d87cbad3f44d/lib/Frontend/InitPreprocessor.cpp#L504))

**GCC** - https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html

**MSVC** - Feature request under investigation https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/96337/feature-request-cpp-threadsafe-static-init.html

Useful on cppreference.com:

- [Feature Test Recommendations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/feature_test)
- [C++ compiler support](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support)

Comment: Thanks. p0096r4 and https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/commit/6a95db8f1217ac08757e05fc6345fb8818f4eef1 was't existed when I asked this question.

Comment: Is quite new for me. Found while researching for https://stackoverflow.com/q/47569145/8918119. Never tried it