# Is it possible to remove dispatch_once in Objective-C++?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c++11, thread-safety, objective-c++

Since C++11, local `static` variables are known to be initialized in a thread safe manner (unless the `-fno-threadsafe-statics` is given), as specified [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102125/is-local-static-variable-initialization-thread-safe-in-c11). Does that mean that the following well-known pattern:

```
+ (NSObject *)onlyOnce {
  static NSObject *object;
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    object = [[NSObject alloc] init];
  });
  return object;
}
```

Can be replaced with the much shorter:

```
+ (NSObject *)onlyOnce {
  static NSObject *object = [[NSObject alloc] init];
  return object;
}
```

When compiling the code as Objective-C++ with C++ language dialect of C++11 and higher?

Comment: It' unfortunate that there is no formal specification of the language, but it could be, if at all, compile dependent. The option -fthreadsafe-statics is listed under GCC/C++ option and as Target independent by clangs clang and clang++ drivers.

Comment: I cannot find `__has_feature` for that but https://stackoverflow.com/q/44500144/8918119 mention a special GCC function `__cxa_guard_acquire` that is used for safe local statics which is also available in clang.

Comment: Looks like the clang pre-processor defines `__cpp_threadsafe_static_init` https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/96c9689f478d292390b76efcea35d87cbad3f44d/lib/Frontend/InitPreprocessor.cpp#L504

Comment: GCC too https://stackoverflow.com/a/47574117/8918119 So someone could try it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** - it seems that it's possible to use C++11 static variable initialization in a thread safe manner which has the same performance characteristics as `dispatch_once`.

Following Stephan Lechner's answer, I wrote the most simple code that tests the C++ static initialization flow:

```
class Object {  
};

static Object *GetObjectCppStatic() {
  static Object *object = new Object();
  return object;
}

int main() {
  GetObjectCppStatic();
}
```

Compiling this to assembly via `clang++ test.cpp -O0 -fno-exceptions -S` (`-O0` to avoid inlining, same general code is produced for `-Os`, `-fno-exceptions` to simplify generated code), shows that `GetObjectCppStatic` compiles to:

```
__ZL18GetObjectCppStaticv:        ## @_ZL18GetObjectCppStaticv
  .cfi_startproc
## BB#0:
  pushq   %rbp
Lcfi6:
  .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Lcfi7:
  .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
  movq  %rsp, %rbp
Lcfi8:
  .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
  cmpb  $0, __ZGVZL18GetObjectCppStaticvE6object(%rip)
  jne LBB2_3
## BB#1:
  leaq  __ZGVZL18GetObjectCppStaticvE6object(%rip), %rdi
  callq   ___cxa_guard_acquire
  cmpl  $0, %eax
  je  LBB2_3
## BB#2:
  movl  $1, %eax
  movl  %eax, %edi
  callq   __Znwm
  leaq  __ZGVZL18GetObjectCppStaticvE6object(%rip), %rdi
  movq  %rax, __ZZL18GetObjectCppStaticvE6object(%rip)
  callq   ___cxa_guard_release
LBB2_3:
  movq  __ZZL18GetObjectCppStaticvE6object(%rip), %rax
  popq  %rbp
  retq
  .cfi_endproc
```

We can definitely see the `___cxa_guard_acquire` and `___cxa_guard_release`, implemented by the libc++ ABI [here](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxxabi/blob/master/src/cxa_guard.cpp). Note that we didn't even had to specify to `clang` that we use C++11, as apparently this was supported by default even prior than that.

So we know both forms ensures thread-safe initialization of local statics. But what about performance? The following test code checks both methods with no contention (single threaded) and with heavy contention (multi threaded):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <dispatch/dispatch.h>
#include <mach/mach_time.h>

class Object {  
};

static double Measure(int times, void(^executionBlock)(), void(^finallyBlock)()) {
  struct mach_timebase_info timebaseInfo;
  mach_timebase_info(&timebaseInfo);

  uint64_t start = mach_absolute_time();
  for (int i = 0; i < times; ++i) {
    executionBlock();
  }
  finallyBlock();
  uint64_t end = mach_absolute_time();

  uint64_t timeTook = end - start;
  return ((double)timeTook * timebaseInfo.numer / timebaseInfo.denom) /
      NSEC_PER_SEC;
}

static Object *GetObjectDispatchOnce() {
  static Object *object;
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    object = new Object();
  });

  return object;
}

static Object *GetObjectCppStatic() {
  static Object *object = new Object();
  return object;
}

int main() {
  printf("Single thread statistics:\n");
  printf("DispatchOnce took %g\n", Measure(10000000, ^{
    GetObjectDispatchOnce();
  }, ^{}));
  printf("CppStatic took %g\n", Measure(10000000, ^{
    GetObjectCppStatic();
  }, ^{}));

  printf("\n");

  dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("queue", 
      DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
  dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

  printf("Multi thread statistics:\n");
  printf("DispatchOnce took %g\n", Measure(1000000, ^{
    dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
      GetObjectDispatchOnce();
    });
  }, ^{
    dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
  }));
  printf("CppStatic took %g\n", Measure(1000000, ^{
    dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
      GetObjectCppStatic();
    });
  }, ^{
    dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
  }));
}
```

Which yields the following results on x64:

```
Single thread statistics:
DispatchOnce took 0.025486
CppStatic took 0.0232348

Multi thread statistics:
DispatchOnce took 0.285058
CppStatic took 0.32596
```

So up to measurement error, it seems that the performance characteristics of both methods are similar, mostly due to the [double-check locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) that is performed by both of them. For `dispatch_once`, this happens in the `_dispatch_once` function:

```
void
_dispatch_once(dispatch_once_t *predicate,
    DISPATCH_NOESCAPE dispatch_block_t block)
{
  if (DISPATCH_EXPECT(*predicate, ~0l) != ~0l) {
    // ...
  } else {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Where in the C++ static initialization flow it happens right before the call to `___cxa_guard_acquire`.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, Objective-C++, which allows mixing Objective-C-Objects and code with C++ objects and code, is a different language than "pure" C++11. Therefore, I don't think that everything guaranteed for C++11 is automatically guaranteed in Objectiver-C++'s mixed world. And I have been spending some time now investigating apple's documentation whether specific guarantees on static local variables or even block variables are also given in Objective-C++.

As I did not find a statement to this, I tried introducing a race condition on the creation of an object, one with the proposed "new style", i.e. using a static local variable, one with the "old style" with `dispatch_once`, and one "real" race condition "notOnlyOnce" ignoring any synchronization (just to be sure that the code actually introduces a race condition).

The tests show that both "new style" and "old style" seem to be thread safe, whereas "notOnlyOnce" clearly is not. Unfortunately, such a test could have just proofen that "new style" produces a race condition, but it cannot proof that there will never be a race condition. But as "new style" and "old style" behave the same, but "notOnlyOnce" shows up a race condition in the same setting, we can at least assume that static local variables work as you proposed.

See the following code and the respective outputs.

```
@interface SingletonClass : NSObject

- (instancetype)init;

@end

@implementation SingletonClass

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    std::cout << "Created a singleton object" << std::endl;
    for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++) { i++; }
    return self;
}

@end

@interface TestClassObjCPP : NSObject 

@property (nonatomic) SingletonClass *sc;

+ (SingletonClass *)onlyOnceNewStyle;
+ (SingletonClass *)onlyOnceOldStyle: (TestClassObjCPP*)caller;
+ (SingletonClass *)notOnlyOnce: (TestClassObjCPP*)caller;

@end

@implementation TestClassObjCPP


+ (SingletonClass *)onlyOnceNewStyle {
    static SingletonClass *object = [[SingletonClass alloc] init];
    return object;
}

+ (SingletonClass *)onlyOnceOldStyle: (TestClassObjCPP*)caller {

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        caller.sc = [[SingletonClass alloc] init];
    });

    return caller.sc;
}

+ (SingletonClass *)notOnlyOnce: (TestClassObjCPP*)caller {

    if (caller.sc == nil)
        caller.sc = [[SingletonClass alloc] init];

    return caller.sc;
}

@end


int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {


    @autoreleasepool {

        std::cout << "Before loop requesting singleton." << std::endl;
        TestClassObjCPP *caller = [[TestClassObjCPP alloc] init];
        caller.sc = nil;
        for (int i=0; i<10000; i++) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                [TestClassObjCPP onlyOnceNewStyle];  // (1)
                // [TestClassObjCPP onlyOnceOldStyle:caller]; // (2)
                // [TestClassObjCPP notOnlyOnce:caller]; // (3)
            });

        }
        std::cout << "After loop requesting singleton." << std::endl;

        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Output for onlyOnceNewStyle (1):

```
Before loop requesting singleton.
Created a singleton object
After loop requesting singleton.
```

Output for onlyOnceOldStyle (2):

```
Before loop requesting singleton.
Created a singleton object
After loop requesting singleton.
```

Output for notOnlyOnce (3):

```
Before loop requesting singleton.
Created a singleton object
Created a singleton object
Created a singleton object
After loop requesting singleton.
```

So not a clear yes or no, but I hope it helps in some way.

Comment: Maybe you wanted to have `static SingletonClass *object` in `onlyOnceNewStyle`?

Comment: @A.A: oops, yes. Copied a version where I tested out something different. But the output is from the version with `static` (otherwise thousands of "object created"-lines would have been outputted.