# static variables in C++ -vs- Objective-C

Tags: c++, objective-c, static

As far as I remember, the keyword `static`, for C++, inside a function call meant that the `static` variable was initialized **the first time the declaration was encountered**.

I have used the `static` keyword in an Objective-C member function and the static variable seems to be initialized immediately (with a non-compile-time constant `subscriber`). **Note**, that I am coding in a mixed file type `.mm` of Objective-C.

```
- (id) init
{
    [self initSubsciber];
    [self relayMessages];
}

- (void) initSubscriber
{
    subscriber= PTR;
}

- (void) relayMessages
{
    // Example 2-2 (mspoller.c), 0MQ book pg.43
    // Initialize poll set
    static zmq_pollitem_t items[] = {
        { subscriber, 0, ZMQ_POLLIN, 0 },
};
```

In the above example, since I am calling `initSubscriber` before `relayMessages`, I would expect the `subscriber`member variable pointer to be equal to PTR, not `NULL`, because the `zmq_pollitem_t` line hasn't been called. Yet, it is `NULL`.

Has the behavior of `static` changed in the various versions of C++? And, how is the behavior defined in Objective-C in comparison?

Comment: No, C didn't change.That what you expect is how C++ works. http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration (and fo C++ lstatic local - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, C didn't change. That what you expect is how C++ works.

### C

[en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration)

> #### Storage duration
>
> [...]
>
> - ***automatic*** storage duration. [...]
> - ***static*** storage duration. The storage duration is the entire execution of the program, and the value stored in the object is
>     initialized only once, prior to main function. All objects declared
>     static and all objects with either internal or external linkage that
>     aren't declared _Thread_local (since C11) have this storage duration.

### C++

[en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration)

> #### Static local variables
>
> Variables declared at block scope with the specifier `static` have static storage duration but are initialized the first time control
>   passes through their declaration (unless their initialization is zero-
>   or constant-initialization, which can be performed before the block is
>   first entered). On all further calls, the declaration is skipped.

### Objective-C++ (.mm)

.mm is Objective-C++, so C++ should apply. But that said there is no official specification of language. So to be sure move in .cpp files and leave only some interfacing code in the .mm. For example it's not clear whether/how the thread-safe local static work ([Is it possible to remove dispatch_once in Objective-C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47569145/8918119)).

[What is Objective C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3684112/8918119)

> Also, you might want to read [Apple's (sadly deleted, but archived)
>   documentation on Objective-C++](http://web.archive.org/web/20101203170217/http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#/web/20101204020949/http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCPlusPlus.html).
>
> -- [doches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3684159/8918119)

Clang has a common unified parser for all C language family[[5](https://clang.llvm.org/features.html#unifiedparser)][[6](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/tree/1ae65827b5b1c280e1db04f7d609a92ddf40e0a9/lib/Parse)] and it looks like the single features are activated depending on the file type/extension and language standard support[[7](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/74a822fbaaac85aebc68c4be95e90a0186707bce/lib/Frontend/CompilerInvocation.cpp#L1761)].

[objective-c++](/questions/tagged/objective-c%2b%2b)

Comment: Ok, but in relation to Objective-C then? If I am using a ``.mm`` file am I compiling with a C or C++ standard? Neither?

Comment: .mm is Objective-C++, so C++. But that said there is no official specification of language. So to be sure move in .cpp files and leave only some interfacing code in the .mm

Comment: The project file says, I am using dialect: LLVM C++ std lib with C++11 support. Compiler warnings state: ISO C++11.

Comment: It all depends on the LLVM Objective-C++ implementation. But as I said no official spec. or documentation. Somehow gray zone :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/3684159/8918119

Comment: I did read the Objective-C guide (a long time ago; still have it) and I remember it says nothing useful.

Comment: I think it's even before LLVM and swift era so maybe now its not C++ extension to Objective-C but the opposite to get most of the C++11 features working. Maybe someone on the Clang team knows better. https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#objective-c-features

Comment: [-rewrite-objc and Objective-C in clang](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44561285/8918119)